# xmpp - how to get room chat history

Tags: history, xmppframework, chatroom, muc

I am using the iOS xmppframework. 
I want to get room chat history when needed. Such that there is a button, when click the button, 20 history messages will be received each time.

If I have 100 history messages, I click the button 5 times, then I will get all the history message.

```
[xmppRoom1 joinRoomUsingNickname:@"myNickname" history:history password:nil];
```

this method can only used once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send history nil
and alos update in openfire
open your openfire url then click on Group chat > Group Chat setting > your group > history setting

[image]

```
XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
        XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@conference.51.101.97.21",groupName]];
        XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                               jid:roomJID
                                                     dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

        [xmppRoom activate:xmppStream];
        [xmppRoom addDelegate:self
                delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:xmppStream.myJID.user
                                history:nil
                               password:nil];
```

Comment: This will get the all history when enter the room. I want to get history message on demand. After I join the room, I want to get the history message at any time.

Comment: If you want history then you must  join a group 
you can change value of history message. if want more history change 10 to 50 or whatever you want
so use this code 
NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
[history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"10"];

[xmppRoom1 joinRoomUsingNickname:@"myNickname" history:history password:nil];

Comment: Thansks suthar. I know I can get room history message when entering the room. But this is not sufficient. If there are a lot of history messages(for example, 10000), I can not get all history message at one time. I need to separate the get history message request into several small requests. Such that I can get 100 messages when entering the room, and I will get another 100 messages if I press a more button.

Comment: Get all history message then save to database then if you need last 50 get those message form localdatabase

Comment: Hi, @KishoreSuthar can you tell me which iq request need to send when fetching one to one chat. I have tried many ways but getting an error code like 405, 500.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method, but can receive anything.

```
NSXMLElement *history = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"history"];
[history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"5"];

NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:XMPPMUCNamespace];
if (history)
{
    [x addChild:history];
}
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:nil to:xmppRoom1.myRoomJID];
[presence addChild:x];
[xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

The message sent and received:

```
SEND: 
<presence to="ios@conference.192.168.1.67/myNickname”>
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc”>
    <history maxstanzas="5”/>
</x>

<x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x>
<c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4=“/>

</presence>


RECV: 
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" from="ios@conference.192.168.1.67/myNickname" to="test1@192.168.1.67/14392264591434445057383183”>
<x xmlns="vcard-temp:x:update"><photo/></x>
<c xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/caps" hash="sha-1" node="https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework" ver="VyOFcFX6+YNmKssVXSBKGFP0BS4=“/>
<x xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user”>
<item jid="test1@192.168.1.67/14392264591434445057383183" affiliation="owner" role="moderator"/><status code="110”/>
</x></presence>
```